# Double number not stored in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, dapper

When trying to save a double into the database, the dot is being removed. This is not happening on my dev machine but only when the code is being deployed on the server.

My view model:

```
public class Session
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Difficulty { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

And the code for saving into the database (using Dapper):

```
using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    dbConnection.Open();

    var query = "INSERT INTO Sessions (CreatedBy, Date, Difficulty, Length) VALUES (@createdBy, @Date, @difficulty, @length)";

    var dp = new DynamicParameters();
    dp.Add("@createdBy", user);
    dp.Add("@date", session.Date);
    dp.Add("@difficulty", session.Difficulty);
    dp.Add("@length", session.Length);

    dbConnection.Execute(query, dp);
}
```

The column `Difficulty` is declared as `Float not null`.

For example, if I submit 6.5, this will be stored as 65 in the database.

If I manually insert something into the database, I do not get any errors (6.5 is stored correctly).

It's only when the deployed code saves the session into the database.

The server is running is Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Comment: Have you tried defining the dbtype in your parameter? `dp.Add("@difficulty", session.Difficulty, DbType.Double, ParameterDirection.Input);`

Comment: I have tried dp.Add("@difficulty", session.Difficulty, DbType.Double). I suspect that there is something wrong with the culture. The server seems to be running under de-De culture... where the decimal point is represented with a comma instead of a dot.

Comment: Well, that is quite an important piece of information. !!

Comment: So I managed to replicate the issue locally, by setting the culture to de-De and then submitting to the db. 6.5 became 65. I have tried this: var ukCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"); and then dp.Add("@difficulty", session.Difficulty.ToString(ukCultureInfo)); but it didn't solve the issue either. Any ideas?

Comment: I think your ToString solution is not working because the session variable is already defining the "actual value" of 65 based on the culture. Switching formats after the fact therefore won't change that, in the same way that switching between US and ISO date format's won't cause the value "third of jan 2020" to become "first of march 2020". See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bz9tc508(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for setting the culture and UI culture of a page in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned I managed to replicate the issue. The server that I deployed my code runs under de-De culture and my dev box under en-Uk.

To resolve the issue, I had to set the Culture in the appSettings to en-Uk and use the defined culture in the StartUp.cs

appSettings.json

```
"Culture": "en-GB"
```

and in the Startup.cs

```
var ukCulture = Configuration["Culture"];
app.UseRequestLocalization(ukCulture);
```